# Formato RUT en TExtview

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo la clase Login siguiente.

```
public class LoginActivity extends ProgressBarActivity implements LoginActivityContract.View {

private final static String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

LoginActivityPresenter presenter;
LoginActivityContract.LifeCycle onLifeCycle;
LoginActivityContract.Action onAction;

public TextView login;
private TextView password;
private Switch login_recordar_rut;
private Button loginButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView texto_version = findViewById(R.id.txt_version);
    String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
    texto_version.setText(versionName);


    login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);

    password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);

    login_recordar_rut = findViewById(R.id.login_recordar_rut);

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    final Activity padre = this;

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View view = padre.getCurrentFocus();

            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

            if (!login.getText().equals("")) {
                enableForm(false);

                String loginText = login.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\-", "").replaceAll("\\.", "");

                onAction.onLoginClick(loginText, password.getText().toString(), login_recordar_rut.isChecked());
            } else {
                showToolTipSB("Formato de Rut incorrecto...");
            }
        }
    });

    tannerApplication app = (tannerApplication) getApplication();

    presenter = new LoginActivityPresenter(this,
            app.getLocalStorage(),
            app.getServerAccessPointSDK(),
            app.getServerAccessPoint(),
            this);

    onLifeCycle = presenter;
    onAction = presenter;

      login.addTextChangedListener(new MaskWatcher(login.toString()));

}

public void enableForm(boolean isEnabled) {
    login.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    password.setEnabled(isEnabled);
}

public void setFocusBoton() {
    return;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    onLifeCycle.onResume(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    onLifeCycle.onPause();
}

@Override
public void setLoginText(@NonNull String text) {
    login.setText(text);
}

@Override
public void setPasswordText(@NonNull String text) {
    password.setText(text);
}

@Override
protected int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.activity_login;
}

@Override
public void showContent() {
    super.showContent();
}

@Override
public void showProgress() {
    super.showProgress();
}

@Override
public void showToolTip(int msg) {
    super.showToolTip(msg);
}

@Override
public void showToolTipSB(String msg) {
    super.showToolTipSB(msg);
}

public void showToolTipSB(int msg) {
    super.showToolTipSB(msg);
}

@Override
public void startRegisterActivity(@NonNull Bundle extras) {
    finish();
}

@Override
protected boolean EjecutaronBackPressed() {
    return true;
}
```

}

como se puede ver, esta hace un llamado a MaskWatcher que es otra clase, pasando el parametro del TextView login.

La clase MaskWatcher es la siguiente.

```
public class MaskWatcher implements TextWatcher {
private boolean isRunning = false;
private boolean isDeleting = false;
private final String mask;
private EditText rutNumber;


public MaskWatcher(String mask) {
    Log.i("MaskWatcher","String mask"+mask);
    this.mask = mask;
}

public static MaskWatcher buildCpf() {
    return new MaskWatcher(" ");
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

    isDeleting = count > after;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {



    String valortext = editable.toString();
    Log.i("MaskWatcher","Valor valortext"+valortext);
    if(valortext.equals(""))
    {
        Log.i("MaskWatcher","Valor valortext 0"+valortext);
        valortext = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("MaskWatcher","Valor valortext !0"+valortext);
         FormatearRUT(valortext); //funcion que formateara el rut
    }
}
public  String FormatearRUT(String rut) {

    Log.i("MaskWatcher","FormatearRUT valor"+rut);
    int cont = 0;
    String format;
    rut = rut.replace(".", "");
    rut = rut.replace("-", "");
    format = "-" + rut.substring(rut.length() - 1);
    for (int i = rut.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        format = rut.substring(i, i + 1) + format;
        cont++;
        if (cont == 3 && i != 0) {
            format = "." + format;
            cont = 0;
        }
    }
    Log.i("MaskWatcher","FormatearRUT valorformat"+format);

    return format;

}
```

}

Al momento de ir ingresando un dato en el TextView se necesita que le entregue el formato de RUT, pero no encuentro la forma de que este quede "impreso en el TextView", cómo lo puedo realizar?.

Comment: Rodrigo a que te refieres con :  quede "impreso en el TextView"

Comment: quise decir, setear los datos en el textview